# Sublime text 3 can't find nodejs installed using nvm

Tags: sublimetext3

Using Sublime Text, I have a file I want to "build" with "Build System" "Node".

When I try to build, I get the following error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/node'
[cmd: ['/usr/local/bin/node', '', '']]
```

I installed node using nvm. How do I get this to work properly?

Note that `which node` yields:
/Users/rolando/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/bin/node

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/node` iis the result of `which node`?

Comment: Try just with `node` as the first value of the `cmd` key `"cmd": ["node", "$file"]`.

Comment: No, the result of `which node` is: /Users/rolando/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/bin/node

Comment: None of those two values work? `node` and/or `/Users/rolando/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/bin/node`?

Comment: where to set this? by default the Build System is looking for /usr/local/bin/node

Comment: Try with `{
  "cmd": ["node", "$file"],
  "selector": "source.js",
  "path": "$PATH:/usr/local/bin/"
}` or `{
  "cmd": ["/Users/rolando/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/bin/node", "$file"],
  "selector": "source.js",
  "path": "$PATH:/usr/local/bin/"
}
`

Comment: If you mean where, then you can go to Tools->Build System->New Build System...->, it'll open a file with some code, paste one of the examples I mentioned you and save it with a custom name, then when you want to build the file for first time, it'll ask you where build system to use.